# How to merge two mySQL database into one?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two database, each contain different tables

leave.sql and crm.sql

I want to transfer all my leave tables into the crm database

How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the other database has different tables then the leaves database then all you need to do is import the data into the crm database. Finally, make sure your leaves script is connected to the new crm database.

Comment: will it replace my other existing table in my crm database?

Comment: If the table names are different than the ones in the leaves database then all it will do is add those tables.

Comment: how about exporting each of your table in 'leave' that you want to import to 'crm'?

Answer (score 1):

Two other methods:

On the mysql prompt, you can rename your tables - and effectively move them from one database to the other (if both are on the same filesystem):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html:

> As long as two databases are on the same file system, you can use
>   RENAME TABLE to move a table from one database to another:

```
RENAME TABLE current_db.tbl_name TO other_db.tbl_name;
```

If you are using MyISAM tables, and you have root privileges, you can just do:

1. stop your mysql server
2. move your tables from the old database directory to the new one
3. start your mysql server

All those assuming the tables in your old database (the ones you want to move) have different names than the ones in your new database (the ones you want to keep). If that's not true, you'll also have to change the names.