# How do I merge two different MySQL server instances

Tags: mysql

I have three servers. I want to copy MySQL database data from 2 servers to third server.

All servers have some or the other data in MySQL server instance running on them.

I didnt have spacy left on the servers so rather than doing mysqldump i just copied database folders i.e. /var/lib/mysql/dbname

Now its showing me names of databases and tables in server where I aggregated all this data (for commands like show databases, show tables) but when I access tables its giving me "Table doesn't exist error"

I am guessing it has something to do with not handling ibdata files in /var/lib/mysql . Given my case what can be done to merge them properly

Answer (score 0):

These two threads effectively solve your issue:

1. If you have the consistent schemas for the three: [How to merge two MySQL databases of same structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068010/how-to-merge-two-mysql-databases-of-same-structure)
2. If you don't have the same schema: [How to merge two mySQL database into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667637/how-to-merge-two-mysql-database-into-one)